# combine both local an push notifications ios

Tags: ios, notifications

Is it possible to combine both local and push notifications in iOS..

For example:An App gets Local Notifications and Push Notifications.

So,Is it possible to combine both badges icon numbers of local and push notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because **for `UILocalNotification` you can not increment badge count by one**, for increment count by one it's handle by server using remote notification.

note: you can adjust badge on local notification like
 `localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = intvalue`

Comment: Can It be possible to display local notification badge icon on view image inside the app.

Comment: yes you can get badge count inside app using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]`